# Error encountered when tagging aws ec2 disks, I have fog-aws version 1.2.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, rubygems, chef-infra, fog

I'm doing aws ec2 disk and snaphot tagging which both fails due to gem conflict on fog 1.29.0 and fog-aws 1.3.0 and I tried installing fog-aws 1.2.0 which resolves snapshot tagging yet got this error on disk tagging.

```
Unexpected error:
    org.codehaus.xfire.fault.XFireFault: Unexpected close tag </body>; expected </HR>.
     at [row,col {unknown-source}]:`enter code here` [1,995]
        at org.codehaus.xfire.fault.XFireFault.createFault(XFireFault.java:89)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.client.Client.onReceive(Client.java:410)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.HttpChannel.sendViaClient(HttpChannel.java:139)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.HttpChannel.send(HttpChannel.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.handler.OutMessageSender.invoke(OutMessageSender.java:26)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline.invoke(HandlerPipeline.java:131)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.client.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:79)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.client.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:114)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.client.Client.invoke(Client.java:336)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.client.XFireProxy.handleRequest(XFireProxy.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.client.XFireProxy.invoke(XFireProxy.java:57)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.describeInstances(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazon.aes.webservices.client.Jec2Impl.describeInstances(Jec2Impl.java:1530)
        at com.amazon.aes.webservices.client.Jec2Impl.describeInstances(Jec2Impl.java:1505)
        at com.amazon.aes.webservices.client.cmd.DescribeInstances.invokeOnline(DescribeInstances.java:58)
        at com.amazon.aes.webservices.client.cmd.BaseCmd.invoke(BaseCmd.java:1064)
        at com.amazon.aes.webservices.client.cmd.DescribeInstances.main(DescribeInstances.java:67)
    Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </body>; expected </HR>.
     at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,995]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:580)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:453)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:438)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.reportWrongEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3234)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3161)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2778)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1054)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.soap.handler.ReadHeadersHandler.invoke(ReadHeadersHandler.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline.invoke(HandlerPipeline.java:131)
        at org.codehaus.xfire.client.Client.onReceive(Client.java:406)
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: The latest fog-aws is 1.4.0, I would start by bumping to that to ensure this hasn't already been fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Failed to run rf_ec2_tagging_disks Result is pid 2417 exit 1. Stderr is: /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2112:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate fog-1.29.0, because fog-aws-1.4.0 conflicts with fog-aws (~> 0.0) (Gem::ConflictError) from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1280:in `activate' from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1314:in `block in activate_dependencies' from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `each' from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `activate_dependencies'

Comment: It looks like something is requiring 0.x of fog-aws (which doesn't match with 1.4). Are you using the latest fog gem as well? You may need to update or remove that (if you are only using fog-aws, you should be fine with just requiring fog-aws and fog-core and not using fog directly).